# Did Playstation require password to be reset as a response to Cloudbleed?

Tags: psn

Last week it became known that Cloudfire had a bug which exposed some sensitive data and has cutely been called [Cloudbleed](https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2017/02/cloudbleed-here-is-a-list-of-websites-confirmed-to-have-been-affected-by-cloudfare-bug/)

> Last week we found out about Cloudbleed, a bug on Cloudflare services that resulted in data leakage from a number of websites.
>
> ...
>
> According to Tavis Ormandy, the Google security researcher who discovered Cloudbleed: "I'm finding private messages from major dating sites, full messages from a well-known chat service, online password manager data, frames from adult video sites, hotel bookings. We're talking full HTTPS requests, client IP addresses, full responses, cookies, passwords, [encryption] keys, data, everything."

last night (27/02/2017 GMT/UTC +10) when i was checking out the Playstation Store on my Vita it required me to change my PSN Password. however the Friday before that (24/02/2017) i was connected to the net and i was playing Ratchet and Clank. when i went into my PSN Trophies they synced and there was no requirement for me to change my password then and i've had this password for a couple of years now which makes me think this wasn't some existing password expiry policy.

The reason I suspect a response from Cloudbleed is because the NISA Forums sent me an email requesting i reset my password and their new policy for resetting password every 3 months in response to Cloudbleed.

> As you may or may not have heard, Cloudflare recently announced a memory
>   leak caused by a parser bug. Our company forums found at
>   www.nisamerica.com/forum are using a Cloudflare proxy service, and while
>   the chance that any forum users are affected is extremely low, we encourage
>   all registered forum users to reset their password.
>
> We will also be automatically resetting forum user's passwords every 3
>   months to ensure the safety and security of your personal information.

So i am wondering, did Playstation require password to be reset as a response to Cloudbleed?

Comment: I noticed last night that I was locked from using Twitch/Netflix/Amazon Video, so possibly? It never prompted me for a password change which was odd. I don't see anything for PSN on [this list of Cloudbleed](https://github.com/pirate/sites-using-cloudflare) websites from github, but that doesn't mean they didn't force a change out of safety.

Comment: How is it last night the 28th when today is the 27th 3 hours away from the 28th? I know there are different time zones but this does not seem possible .-.

Comment: It's been downright disturbing how few of the companies on that list have responded to this.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket sorry about that. looked at the calendar and forgot today was Tuesday not Wednesday. added my timezone just to clear up any other confusion